# C++ - How to write back JSON into file

Tags: c++, json, c++11

I'm using library from https://github.com/nlohmann/json
I need to write my JSON into file but I can't find anythink about that in doc.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 5):

You can write a JSON value `j` into a file like this:

```
std::ofstream o("output.json");
o << j << std::endl;
```

If you want the output to be prettified, use:

```
std::ofstream o("pretty.json");
o << std::setw(4) << j << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can dump the json object into a string with the `dump()` method and then write that into a file.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem today, as Niels stated you can just write the json directly to a file using the shift operator, but this doesn't save it with any whitespace so it's not very human readable. For example,

```
int main() {
    nlohmann::json data;

    data["Some String"] = "Hello World";
    data["Some Number"] = 420;
    data["Empty Array"] = nlohmann::json::array_t();
    data["Array With Items"] = { true, "Hello", 3.1415 };
    data["Empty Array"] = nlohmann::json::array_t();
    data["Object With Items"] = nlohmann::json::object_t({{"Key", "Value"}, {"Day", true}});
    data["Empty Object"] = nlohmann::json::object_t();

    std::ofstream output_file("settings_example_output.json");
    if (!output_file.is_open())  {
        std::cout << "\n Failed to open output file";
    } else {
        output_file << data;
        output_file.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

yields a json file that looks like

```
{"Array With Items":[true,"Hello",3.1415],"Empty Array":[],"Empty Object":{},"Object With Items":{"Day":true,"Key":"Value"},"Some Number":420,"Some String":"Hello World"}
```

so instead I wrote a export_json function that'll insert the appropriate whitespace:

```
template<typename ITERATOR_TYPE>
void print_element(ITERATOR_TYPE it, unsigned int depth, std::ostream& output_stream);
void print_array(nlohmann::json::array_t arr, unsigned int depth, std::ostream& output_stream);
void print_object(nlohmann::json obj, unsigned int depth, std::ostream& output_stream);

void export_json(nlohmann::json json_file, std::ostream& output_stream) {
    output_stream << "{\n";

    for (nlohmann::json::iterator iter = json_file.begin();;) {
        output_stream << '\t' << '"' << iter.key() << "\": ";
        
        print_element(iter, 1, output_stream);

        if (++iter != json_file.end()) {
            output_stream << ',' << '\n';
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    output_stream << "\n}";
}

void print_array(nlohmann::json::array_t arr, unsigned int depth, std::ostream& output_stream) {
    if (!arr.size())
        return;

    std::string indent = std::string(depth, '\t');
    for (nlohmann::json::array_t::iterator iter = arr.begin();;) {
        output_stream << '\n' << indent << '\t';
        print_element(iter, depth + 1, output_stream);

        if (++iter != arr.end()) {
            output_stream << ',';
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    output_stream << '\n' << indent;
}

void print_object(nlohmann::json obj, unsigned int depth, std::ostream& output_stream) {
    if (!obj.size())
        return;

    std::string indent = std::string(depth, '\t');
    for (nlohmann::json::iterator iter = obj.begin();;) {
        output_stream << '\n' << indent << '\t' << '"' << iter.key() << "\": ";
        print_element(iter, depth + 1, output_stream);

        if (++iter != obj.end()) {
            output_stream << ',';
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    output_stream << '\n' << indent;
}

template<typename ITERATOR_TYPE>
void print_element(ITERATOR_TYPE iter, unsigned int depth, std::ostream& output_stream) {
    switch (iter->type())
    {
    case nlohmann::json::value_t::object:
        output_stream << '{';
        print_object(nlohmann::json(*iter), depth, output_stream);
        output_stream << '}';
        break;

    case nlohmann::json::value_t::array:
    

output_stream << '[';
    print_array(nlohmann::json::array_t(*iter), depth, output_stream);
    output_stream << ']';
    break;

default:
    output_stream << *iter;
    break;
}
```

}

Of course, if no ones goin to be reading the file then this is overkill and I would just use the simpler solutions mentioned before. Personally I want to use it to generate settings files that I can directly edit so I needed the whitespace.